# How to package linked java file also using maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was experimenting one project.So,i needed some utility function from another project.So, I drag that file into my project,then, eclipse prompted me that whether it should link that java file or copy java file into this project.i linked that java file. But,When package using maven, i could not find that linked java file in "jar". How to achive this?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me what you want to know. Please give a detailed example.

Comment: @JFMeier sorry, i corrected now. could you check?

Comment: Why do you want to link a Java file? Why not just copy it?

Comment: @JFMeier I might to do some changes in that funtionality. So,that should do affect on other project too .if copy it, after changes, Then, again copy those changes to other project. which is redundant work.

Comment: No, this is not the way you share classes in Java. If you need some classes in more than one project, you put them in a separate project (say `common`) and build a `common.jar`. Now you use `common.jar` as dependency in your other projects.

Comment: @JFMeier i agree. But, i wonder .is there any way to  achive this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205511/discussion-between-jagadeesh-k-and-jf-meier).